# Have Zuul edge service automatically use microservice's basic auth credentials

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to build an edge service that uses zuul to call a microservice through Eureka. The microservice requires basic auth. Previously, Ribbon was detecting the credentials and setting the auth header. But now when I hit the endpoint through the zuul proxy, it's prompting me to login with the microservice credentials.

Can someone tell me how to configure zuul to do what Ribbon had been doing? Or is it not even possible?

Spring cloud verision is Dalston

spring boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Edge service uses cas authentication

**zuul configuration**

```
zuul:
    routes:
        my-msv:
            # for now
            sensitiveHeaders:
```

**main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@RestController
class ZuulDemoApplication {


    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    fun restOps(): RestOperations {
        return RestTemplate()
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun sayHello() = "hello!"

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZuulDemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your Zuul proxy a discovery client:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient // <--- This should do it with defaults
@EnableZuulProxy
@RestController
class ZuulDemoApplication {


    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    fun restOps(): RestOperations {
        return RestTemplate()
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun sayHello() = "hello!"

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZuulDemoApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```